# Cutting a text file into multiple parts in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am using the GNU Emacs 23 editor. I have this huge text file containing about 10,000 lines which I want to chop into multiple files. Using the mouse to select the required text to paste in another file is the really painful.  Also this is prone to errors too.

If I want to divide the text file according to the line numbers into say 4 file where 
first file:lines 1-2500
second file:lines 2500-5000
third file :lines 5000-7500
fourth file: lines: 7500-10000

how do I do this? At  the very least, is there any efficient way to copy large regions of the file just by specifying line numbers

Comment: You can still use the `split` shell command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C-u is your friend. Try this:

```
C-spc (set mark at point)
C-u 2500 <down> (equivalent to pressing the down key 2500 times)
M-w (copy)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is very useful. Is there a way to specify the file to copy the region to while doing this process?

Comment: Instead of M-w, you can use M-x append-to-file - this command asks for a filename, then takes whatever is in the current region and appends it to that file.

Answer (score 3):

The following should work:

```
M-<           (go to start of file)
C-space       (set mark at current cursor position)
ESC 2500 down (go down 2500 lines)
C-w           (delete between mark and cursor, and put it in cut buffer)
...           (open new file, using your favourite method)
C-Y           (paste contents of cut buffer)
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this command, from `misc-cmds.el` (http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/misc-cmds.el).  You just select the text you want and then copy it to the file you want -- see the doc string.

```
    (defun region-to-file (start end filename arg)
      "With prefix arg, this is `append-to-file'.  Without, it is `write-region'.
    START and END are the region boundaries.
    Prefix ARG non-nil means append region to end of file FILENAME.
    Prefix ARG nil means write region to FILENAME, replacing contents."
      (interactive
       (list (region-beginning) (region-end)
             (read-file-name (concat (if current-prefix-arg "Append" "Write")
                                     " region to file: "))
             current-prefix-arg))
      (let* ((curr-file (buffer-file-name))
             (same-file-p (and curr-file (string= curr-file filename))))
        (cond ((or (not same-file-p)
                   (progn
                     (when (fboundp 'flash-ding) (flash-ding))
                     (yes-or-no-p
                      (format
                       "Do you really want to REPLACE the contents of `%s' by \
    just the REGION? "
                       (file-name-nondirectory curr-file)))))
               (write-region start end filename arg)
               (when same-file-p (revert-buffer t t)))
              (t (message "OK.  Not written.")))))
```